# Unique base b representations via lexicographic order

Tags: elementary-number-theory, reference-request

Fix a base $b \neq 0$.  To a sequence of non-negative integers $(c_i), i \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $c_i = 0$ for $i \gg 0$, associate the sum

$$\sum_{i=-\infty}^{\infty} c_i b^i$$

We can order such sequences lexicographically: if $c_i = 0$ for $i \geq  n$ and $d_n \neq 0$ then $(c_i) < (d_i)$, and otherwise we can compare $c_{n-1}$ to $d_{n-1}$, etc.

Among all such sequences with sum $x$, we can declare the base-$b$ representation of $x$ to be the one which is lexicographically last.

This seems to have pretty nice properties:

- If $b\geq 2$ is an integer then this gives the (or at least a) usual base $b$ representation.
- We take $1.000\ldots$ rather than $0.999\ldots$ as the base ten representation of 1, and similarly for other numbers and bases.
- We don't have to artificially declare that the digits are smaller than the base, meaning that everything smoothly generalizes to negative and/or non-integer bases.

Two questions:

- Does this have a name or has it been studied before?
- It seems like with a slight modification we should be able to get the base-1 representation of a positive integer to reduce to tallies, but I don't see a way to do this that feels natural.  (E.g. you could sort by the largest digit appearing and then lexicographically or something but that seems like forcing the issue.)  Is there a clean way to tweak the definition to get this to work?

(Tags aren't quite right but couldn't find anything better... Feel free to suggest improvements.)

Comment: You might find of interest: Rota et al. [The real numbers as a wreath product.](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82803529.pdf). See [here](https://math.ou.edu/~dmccullough/teaching/slides/rotamath.pdf) for an introduction.

Comment: Thanks, this looks very relevant.